# Why is there a factor of 1.7159 with the tanh function used in neural network activation?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperbolic-functions, neural-networks

I was reading about neural networks when I came across the line : 
Recommended f (x) = 1.7519 tanh (2/3 * x). How do we arrive at these values (we can fix the other once the other is obtained using the condition f(1) = 1) ?
Pg 10 at [Efficient Backprop](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf)

Comment: Could you state _where_ you came across the line, and what it is the unknown author recommends that particular function _for_?

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Pg 10 at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf

Comment: Check in reference [19] of said paper to find out why these figures are "recommended". Not coming from the "Learning community" we don't know what a "sigmoid function" is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If you read further, at the top of page 14 it states that the required conditions for the sigmoid are:

1. $f(\pm1)=\pm1$
2. The second derivative is a maximum at $x=1$
3. The effective gain is close to 1

Once you've decided that a $\tanh$ curve is a useful curve to try to fit to your sigmoid, then it is a case of choosing prameters.